# Misleading note on profile editing page

Tags: bug, profile-page, age

According to [this post](/q/294637/350567), age is no longer publicly visible (except for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer and Data Dump).

[image: I can hide a spam link here, haha]

What about the indicative text?

Comment: Well, it *is* shown to moderators (but it counts as accessing Personally Identifiable Information).

Comment: @Glorfindel Shown to mods ≠ publicly visible.

Comment: ... and it shows the birthday itself, not the age.

Comment: I don't think the field should be removed, e.g. maybe one day SE will decide to send birthday gifts to users... who knows.... but yes, the text is now a bug, leftover of the times where age was displayed.

Comment: I personally think the test might as well be removed. And add *visible to moderators* to the (grey) parentheses above.

Comment: The age is returned by the Stack Exchange API for every user (who ever has populated that field), so removing that warning would not be accurate.

Comment: @BhargavRao Than ***changing*** it would make more sense.